# Animation anchor scroll - Back To Top button fades more than once

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am still learning jquery and tried to make a animation anchor scroll. My code seems to work, however, it adds an extra fadeIn/ fadeOut on the Back To Top button when the animation is complete. Can someone please let me know what I did wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.anchor').click(function(){
       var anchorAttr = $(this).attr('data-title');
       var anchorPos = $('#' + anchorAttr).offset().top;

       $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: anchorPos});
    });

   var backtoTop = $('a.backtotop');
     backtoTop.hide();

   $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
                backtoTop.fadeOut();
            } else {
                backtoTop.fadeIn();
            }
        });

    backtoTop.click(function () {
        $('body,html').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinh/RmyxK/

Answer (score 0):

Change your click function to this :

```
backtoTop.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);

});
```

What's happening is that when you click on back to top, you go top first, then activate the fadeout condition. Then you go back to where you was and activate fadeIn condition. Finally you move back to top, activating again the fadeout condition.

All those fade are queuing up and you see all of them happen. adding `e.preventDefault()`. will vancel the default behavior which is going back to top.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RmyxK/5/

Comment: If it wasnt an # anchor than e.preventDefault is not needed? 
Is there a better way to code what I have and get the same outcome? Still learning jQuery.

Comment: preventing default is alway better since without the #, you lost the functionnality of the `a` (mainly the cursor). Yes you could remove the `#` and use css to change the cursor, but it's a standar that the `a` must have an href like an `img` must have a src. Also, if JS is disabled, the back to top will still work if the href is `#`.